# What to do with thread being about to terminate?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm having a running thread that is about to terminate, but at that point, I already want to get rid of its reference. Can I just kick it off and hope for the best or should I handle it in some special way?

```
class CoolThing(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = None

    def run_in_background(self, callback, period=0.5):
        if self.thread:
            raise RuntimeError

        def worker():
            worker.running = True
            while worker.running:
                if some_event():
                    callback(self)
                time.sleep(period)

        self.thread = (threading.Thread(target=worker), worker)
        self.thread[0].start()

    def stop_background(self, join=False):
        if not self.thread:
            raise RuntimeError

        # Make the worker function end harmfully.
        self.thread[1].running = False

        if join:
            self.thread[0].join()

        # What should I now do with the thread being about to
        # terminate, when not being joined?

        # ...

        self.thread = None
```

Comment: My first instinct was `self.thread[0].join()`, but that doesn't seem to kill the thread, it only waits for the thread to finish execution ...

Comment: @mgilson: Right. I don't want `stop_background()` to block if not explicity requested (see edit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set thread to None in a callback that is evoked from within `worker`, when the while-loop is left:

**Edit**: Now also support immediate restart of background process

```
import time
import threading

class CoolThing(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = None

    def run_in_background(self, callback, period=0.5):
        wait_count = 0
        while True:
            if self.thread:
                if self.thread[1].running or wait_count>10:
                    raise RuntimeError()
                time.sleep(0.5)
                wait_count += 1
            else:
                break

        def worker():
            t0 = time.time()
            worker.running = True
            while worker.running:
                if time.time()-t0>2:
                    callback()
                    t0 = time.time()
                time.sleep(period)
            worker.callback()

        worker.callback = self.dispose
        self.thread = (threading.Thread(target=worker), worker)
        self.thread[0].start()

    def stop_background(self, join=False):
        if not self.thread:
            raise RuntimeError
        self.thread[1].running = False
        if join:
            self.thread[0].join()
        self.stopping = True

    def dispose(self):
        self.thread = None
        self.stopping

def my_callback():
    print "Beep"

if __name__=="__main__":
    cool_thing = CoolThing()
    cool_thing.run_in_background(my_callback, 0.5)
    time.sleep(10)
    cool_thing.stop_background()
    # Immediatley restart process
    cool_thing.run_in_background(my_callback, 0.5)
    time.sleep(10)
    cool_thing.stop_background()
    print cool_thing.thread
    time.sleep(3)
    print cool_thing.thread
```

gives the output:

```
Beep
Beep
Beep
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 10760)>, <function worker at 0x02DEDD70>)
None
```

So immediately after calling stop_background, self.thread is still set, but later, it's `None`. You could also save on the worker.callback-variable and call dispose() by it's name, but this way, the code is more flexible.

**Edit 2**: New requirements, new code sample

I made a separate class for worker (SRP) and CoolThing hold a list of such workers. If `run_background(...)` is started, it checks if any of the workers is still running (no stop requested), then raises RuntimeError. Otherwise, starts a new worker. 
`stop_background()` tells each worker to stop, and each worker invokes a callback, which then removes this worker from the list of all workers.

```
import time
import threading

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, callback, period=0.5, finished_callback = None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.callback = callback
        self.period = period
        self._stop_requested = False
        self._finished_callback = finished_callback

    def run(self):
        t0 = time.time()
        while not self._stop_requested:
            if time.time()-t0>2:
                self.callback()
                t0 = time.time()
            time.sleep(self.period)
        if self._finished_callback:
            self._finished_callback(self)

    def request_stop(self):
        self._stop_requested = True

    @property
    def stopping(self):
        return self._stop_requested

class CoolThing(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.workers = []
        self.workers_lock = threading.Lock()

    def run_in_background(self, callback, period=0.5):
        if len([w for w in self.workers if not w.stopping])>0:
            raise RuntimeError()
        worker = Worker(callback, period, finished_callback=self.dispose)
        with self.workers_lock:
            self.workers.append(worker)
        worker.start()

    def stop_background(self, join=False):
        if len(self.workers) == 0:
            raise RuntimeError()
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.request_stop()
        if join:
            for worker in self.workers:
                worker.join()

    def dispose(self, worker):
        with self.workers_lock:
            self.workers.remove(worker)

def my_callback():
    print "Beep"

if __name__=="__main__":
    cool_thing = CoolThing()
    cool_thing.run_in_background(my_callback, 0.5)
    time.sleep(10) 
    print cool_thing.workers
    cool_thing.stop_background()
    # Immediatley restart process
    cool_thing.run_in_background(my_callback, 0.5)    
    print cool_thing.workers
    time.sleep(5)
    print cool_thing.workers
    time.sleep(5)
    cool_thing.stop_background()
    print cool_thing.workers
    time.sleep(3)
    print cool_thing.workers
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What immediately appeared to me: I cannot successfully invoke `run_in_background()` right after `stop_background()` has been called, because `thread` would still be set and `RuntimeError` would be raised. Do you also have a solution for this?

Comment: Sure. Will adjust my sample.

Comment: Adjusted sample to include this feature. If thread is stopping, but not yet None, will retry ten times (with sleep in between). I avoided using a Lock as it can block your code. Deadlocks are serious problems.

Comment: I don't like this approach. If the period of the running thread is set too high,`run_in_background()` would raise a RuntimeError, although `stop_background()` was called before. The behavior of the function is therefore not consistent. I would like to garuantee that when `stop_background()` was called before, `run_in_background()` can be called immediately after that. Also, I would like both calls to be non-blocking (and `run_in_background()` now is blocking).

Comment: It is not blocking! Just waiting. Please clarify your desired behaviour. If worker.running is set to False, but the Thread didn't yet terminate, and you then call `run_in_background()`: what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I might a have a wrong definition of blocking in mind, sorry. Well ok, it's waiting. What I expected, is that it starts the new thread *immediately*.

Comment: New sample that hopefully meets your requirements.

Comment: 1. How can `len()` return None? 2. Could you please explain why we need a lock to append the worker to the list of workers? 3. Thank you, this seems to work very fine. :)

Comment: __1.__ was wrong, fixed it, __2.__ we have to points in the code where we alter the list, whenever a worker is created and when it terminates and is being removed from the list. These are executed in different threads, and thus, as lists aren't thread-safe, we have to use a Lock, so that only one thread at a time changes our list. __3.__ You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter already mentioned, you can't use `join()` because all that does is wait for the thread to terminate naturally. I'm not aware of any native Python API to forcibly kill a thread, although the underlying threading libraries will typically have one (e.g. `pthread_kill()`). This is generally because forcibly killing a thread in Python is generally a pretty bad thing to do.

In this case, however, it doesn't appear you're trying to kill an uncooperative thread, you've signalled to the thread that you want it to terminate gracefully (by setting your `running` attribute).

I don't see any reason why you can't just set `thread` to `None` straight away - I don't believe that removing the last reference to the thread object will actually cause any problems as the thread will be kept alive until it terminates (unless you've set `daemon` to `True` on it and the main program terminates). Of course, any objects that are in the closure created when you define the `worker()` function will still exist, so they won't be freed until the thread terminates (and possibly not even then the way that closure is set up - I'd need to think about that more carefully).

Anyway, I think your life will be easier if you just arrange to `join()` with the thread when it terminates. If your concern is that you will have to wait for your thread's period to time out, you can use a `threading.Condition` object to get around that:

```
class CoolThing(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = None
        self.exit_condition = threading.Condition()

    def run_in_background(self, callback, period=0.5):
        if self.thread:
            raise RuntimeError

        def worker(exit_condition):
            exit_condition.acquire()
            worker.running = True
            while worker.running:
                if some_event():
                    callback(self)
                exit_condition.wait(period)
            exit_condition.release()

        self.thread = (threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(self.exit_condition,)),
                       worker)
        self.thread[0].start()

    def stop_background(self):
        if not self.thread:
            raise RuntimeError

        # Make the worker function end harmfully.
        self.exit_condition.acquire()
        self.thread[1].running = False
        self.exit_condition.notify()
        self.exit_condition.release()

        self.thread[0].join()
        self.thread = None
```