# Close multi threaded application with KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, pygame

I have an app with two threads. One is a pygame thread which runs a simple game, the other thread is a listening server which accepts messages which are used to control the game.

Here is the stripped down pseudo code:

```
class ServerThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        class SingleTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
            try:
                while(1):
                ...
                #Receive messages from socket. Add them to pygame event queue
                ...
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                sys.exit(0)
...
...
class PygameThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
    ...
    #pygame stuff
    ...
    #The following pygame code closed the app when closing the pygame window while running as a single thread
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==QUIT:
                    exit()
   ...
try:
    server_thread = ServerThread()
    server_thread.start()
    pygame_thread = PygameThread()
    pygame_thread.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(0)
```

It seems that none of the exceptions are being caught. I've tried running just the server without the pygame thread and the:

```
        try:
            while(1):
            ...
            #Receive messages from socket. Add them to pygame event queue
            ...
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(0)
```

doesn't respond to `Ctrl + c`

The pygame window standard close button (the little x op right) doesn't work anymore.

And my try of a workaround:

```
try:
    server_thread = ServerThread()
    server_thread.start()
    pygame_thread = PygameThread()
    pygame_thread.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(0)
```

also isn't working.

I'm looking for ideas to close the app without having to kill the shell from which the app has been started.

**Updated**

Based on the suggestion i did the following:
Changed the former `while True` in both treads to `while not self.stop_requested:`.

And also:

```
try:
    pygame_thread = PygameThread()
    pygame_thread.start()
    server_thread = ServerThread()
    server_thread.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pygame_thread.stop_requested = True
    server_thread.stop_requested = True
```

It still isn't working. I also noticed that in the console which runs this code when I try to terminate with Ctrl+c, it only gets printed out.

```
alan@alan ~/.../py $ python main.py 
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
```

**Updated**

I did a little shortcut and changed the server thread to daemon, so it closes once the pygame window (which is tha pygame thread) is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `except`-block of your main program, you should somehow notify your `Thread`s to stop on their own. You can look at my answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215047/what-to-do-with-thread-being-about-to-terminate/14215387#14215387) to get an idea of what I mean.

Basically, substitute the `while(1):`-loop by a `while not self.stop_requested:`-loop. You can then set this field of your class from inside your main thread, where the `KeyboardInterrupt` is actually caught. Then you should also `join()` each thread from your main thread, and then you safely know everthing stopped.

BTW: I would not use `while(1)` at all. `while True` is more intuitive, as the 1 is evaluated as a `bool` each iteration of the loop. Why not write a `bool` where it is expected? The parentheses are redundant as well. This kind of notation goes back to good-old C, which doesn't have a boolean-type.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.exit` is somewhat confusing name, since it doesn't actually terminate or "exit" anything. It only throws an exception, and if you do that in a thread, the exception remains local to that thread. To throw `SystemExit` in the main context you're going to need [`thread.interrupt_main`](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.interrupt_main).