# Multi-threaded code keeps printing even after KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a very simple multi-threaded python code with two threads trying to pop and print from a queue. I use a lock to ensure mutual exclusion. Everything works fine, except:

1. If I import python's in-built `Queue`, the program exits on `KeyboardInterrup` from the terminal
2. If I define a custom `class Queue(object)` (internally implemented as a `list`), the threads keep printing to the terminal even after a `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Here is my code: https://ideone.com/ArTcwE (Although you cannot test `KeyboardInterrupt` on ideone)

PS: I've gone through [Close multi threaded application with KeyboardInterrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274327/close-multi-threaded-application-with-keyboardinterrupt) already. It doesn't solve my problem.

**UPDATE 1**: I understand (thanks to @SuperSaiyan's answer) why the threads would continue to work in scenario# 2 - the master function died before `job_done` could be set to `True`. Hence, the threads kept waiting for the signal to arrive. But what's strange is that even in scenario# 1, `job_done` is still `False`. The threads somehow get killed:

```
>>> execfile('threaded_queue.py')
Starting Q1Starting Q2

Q1 got 0
Q2 got 1
Q1 got 2
Q1 got 3


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#68>", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('threaded_queue.py')
  File "threaded_queue.py", line 54, in <module>
    while not q.empty():
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> job_done
False
>>>
```

**UPDATE 2**: Pasting the code here for permanency:

```
from time import time, ctime, sleep
from threading import Thread, Lock
from Queue import Queue

class MyQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.store = []

    def put(self, value):
        self.store.append(value)

    def get(self):
        return self.store.pop(0)

    def empty(self):
        return not self.store


class SyncQueue(Thread):
    __lock = Lock()

    def __init__(self, name, delay, queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.delay = delay
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        print "Starting %s" % self.name
        while not self.queue.empty():
            with self.__lock:
                print "%s got %s" % (
                        self.name,
                        self.queue.get())
            sleep(self.delay)
        while not job_done:
            sleep(self.delay)
        print "Exiting %s" % self.name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    job_done = False
    #q = Queue(5) # Python's Queue
    q = MyQueue() # Custom Queue
    for i in xrange(5):
        q.put(i)
    q1 = SyncQueue("Q1", .5, q)
    q2 = SyncQueue("Q2", 1, q)
    q1.start()
    q2.start()

    # Wait for the job to be done
    while not q.empty():
        pass
    job_done = True
    q1.join()
    q2.join()
    print "All done!"
```

Comment: If you run the code with Python's `Queue` you will see `AttributeError: Queue instance has no attribute 'peek'`. That means that both threads die before you interrupt it. And when you do there is nothing to wait for an the interpreter exits. On the other hand if you "add" a `peek` method to Python's `Queue` then the behaviour will be the same.

Comment: @freakish So sorry, my bad. The code was stale. I wasn't originally using `peek` in my code with python's `Queue`. Please check the code again on ideone now.

Comment: ideone seems to be down. Can you paste the whole code here on SO?

Comment: Oops, did I bring it down lol. (It seems to be back up again)

Comment: You should paste the whole code here in case it goes down again.

Comment: @freakish You're totally right. It's gonna expire anyways. Updated the question with the code.

Comment: Anyway, I've tested your updated code and it behaves exactly the same with both queues. I even tested it with `execfile` (in case it does something weird) but it didn't matter.

Comment: Man, that's what @SuperSaiyan is saying too. Not a clue what's happening. What terminal are you using? I'm on `IDLE Python 2.7.11` for Windows.

Comment: I'm testing it under ubuntu. Unfortunately I can't test it under Windows. It might matter although it would be weird.

Comment: I'll test this in Linux once I have access, and update here. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not your custom `Queue` v/s python's `Queue`. It is something else altogether. Further, even with python's `Queue` implementation you would see the same behaviour.

This is because your main thread dies when your press `ctrl+C` before it is able to signal the other two threads to exit (using `job_done = True`).

What you need is a mechanism to tell your other two threads to exit. Below is a simple mechanism -- you might need something more robust but you'd get the idea:

```
try:
    while not job_done:
        time.sleep(0.1)  #Trying using this instead of CPU intensive `pass`.
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    job_done = True
```

Comment: a) Sorry about the `peek`. It's something I forgot to comment out. Please check the code again on ideone now.
b) `Even with python's Queue implementation you would see the same behaviour` - that's not true. I don't know if it's something different about my terminal (IDLE Python on Windows), but if that was the case, I wouldn't post the problem in the first place :)

Comment: What you said makes sense, but doesn't help me. Please see the **UPDATE 1** section in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @th3an0maly: Can you run in out in a terminal? (`python file.py` ?) I am certain you'd see the behaviour there..